# List Product / Combinations With Strings

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this in Mathematica:

```
list1 = {{"A"},{"B","C"}}
```

I am trying to output a second list that has the combinations of these elements but while maintaining the order, i.e., A should come first:

```
list2 = {{"A","B"},{"A","C"}}
```

But, I am not sure how to do this efficiently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute):

```
Distribute[list1, List]
```

> {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "C"}}

Answer (score 7):

```
Tuples @ list1
```

> {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "C"}}